# Infragistics WebDialogWindow FadeOut on Close

Tags: javascript, css, infragistics

I am creating a dialog window for a program.  It will be a simple popup that can display whatever message we pass, as well as an image for success or error.

I can make the WebDialogWindow fade in by simply adding the CSS class "FadeIn3" to the window itself. (Code is below)  The window fades into view and works great.  I have a button inside the window that will call a Javascript function to close the window.  When that's clicked, instead of the window instantly disappearing I'd like to have the window fade away over the course of 1 or 2 seconds.  Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

**WebDialogWindow**

```
<ig:WebDialogWindow ID="dialogMessage" runat="server" WindowState="Hidden" 
Width="300px" Height="150px" Modal="true" InitialLocation="Centered" 
CssClass="fadeIn3" StyleSetName="Default">

    ...

    <asp:Button ID="btnCloseWindow" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClick="return hideWindow();" />
</ig:WebDialogWindow>
```

**CSS**

```
.fadeIn3 {
-webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
   -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox < 16 */
     -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
        animation: fadein 3s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function hideWindow() {
    oDialog1 = $find('<%= dialogMessage.ClientID %>');

    //I think I need something here to add a "fadeOut" CSS class to the window
    // that would cause it to fade out.  If I add it directly to the
    // CSSClass property then the window fades in, fades out, then appears
    // until the close button is clicked, at which point it instantly disappears.

    oDialog1.set_windowState($IG.DialogWindowState.Hidden);

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you think jQuery "fadeOut" method would do the work for you?
It would look like something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function complete() {
        oDialog1 = $find('<%= dialogMessage.ClientID %>');
        oDialog1.set_windowState($IG.DialogWindowState.Hidden);
        return false;
    }

    function hideWindow() {
        $("#dialogMessage").fadeOut(2000, complete);
        return false;

    }
</script>
```

You can set the animation's duration in the first argument (in the example - 2 seconds). 
[.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up making 2 fadeInOut CSS classes, one for 3 seconds, and one for 5.  Then I apply that class to the dialog window, and call a function called timedHide() with the same number of seconds. That function will wait that many seconds and then call the original hideWindow() function at around the same time the fadeInOut script is finishing up.

CSS

```
@keyframes fadeinout {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  10%{opacity: .2;}
  20%{opacity: .4;}
  30%{opacity: .6;}
  40%{opacity: .8;}
  50%{opacity: 1;}
  60%{opacity: .8;}
  70%{opacity: .6;}
  80%{opacity: .4;}
  90%{opacity: .2;} 
  100% {opacity: 0;}        
}
```

Javascript

```
function timedHide(numSeconds) {
    var timeout = 1000 * numSeconds;

    setTimeout("hideWindow()", timeout);
}
```